# how can recreate an iso image file of an O.S?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am M.C.A student

I want to make changes in Windows xp O.S. after changes in O.S. using regeitry, I want to create and image file of a Win Xp O.S. how can I do?

Comment: More of a question for Server Fault, I think.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you want to create a modified installation disk but there's also the small chance that you want to make an image (read: backup) of the installed system so that you can restore it later. If meant image as in backup then please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not quite sure what's being asked here, but it sounds like you might want to have certain registry settings applied by the operating system disk. Is that the case? If so, you will want to look into creating an unattended setup disk. There is a fantastic guide to this called the [MSFN Unattended XP Guide](http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp/), and they also have forums with lots of people experienced with how to create these disks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if your desired changes are possible to to within the graphical user interface of [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/). The software is pretty much self explaining. If I remember correctly there is also an option for commands to be executed after the installation. So you can export the registry changes and put them on the CD and should be able to import the ".reg" file automatically after the installation.